# How to list the Realm List in getView in an activity?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am able to print the school names in my main activity using the adapter as following code.

My question is if I click the school name and want to list the student names in another student activity, how can I list the students names for `RealmList<Student> Students`, and how can I specify the students' position in the student adapter?

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView school;
    }

    public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        School item = realmResults.get(position);
        viewHolder.school.setText(item.getSchoolName());
        return convertView;
    }

    public RealmResults<School> getRealmResults() {
        return realmResults;
    }
}

public class School extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private String SchoolID;
    private String SchoolName;
    private RealmList<Student> Students;

    //...getters/setters
}


public class Student extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private String StudentID;
    private String StudentName;

    //...getters/setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You should implement an OnItemClick listener for your school listview:

```
listViewSchool.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
    {
        // Get the School Name from School Adapter

        String schoolName = ((School) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)).[GetSchoolName()]; 

        // Create intent to pass data and call another Activity.

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, [YourStudentActivity].class);

        // Add data to intent

        intent.putExtra("schoolName", schoolName);

        // Call the Student Activity

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

2 - You should filter the students by School Name in the OnCreate() when Student Activity is created and show them in the student listview. To get the value coming from the intent:

```
// OnCreate on Student Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null)
    {
        String schoolName = extras.getString("schoolName");
    }

    // Then filter the students by [schoolName] and then add the result to the student array used by the student adapter and then notify the student listview.

    ...
}
```

Maybe it could help: [Getting wrong result in Android application from PHP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971959/getting-wrong-result-in-android-application-from-php-server/31974052#31974052)

Q: Why do you need to specify the student positions in the student adapter?

Answer (score 1):

```
you have to implement the onclick for school row and o click of that have to call another activity with putting school id as extra. 

then on student you have to fetch students list on the basis of school id you send from first list. and the generate the list here.
```